# how can i check if an element visible without stopping the program from running in cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

When I try to look for an element in the software I am working on and it is not found the automation stops.
What can I do so that if the element is not found the automation will continue to run?

Comment: Please the add the code you tried along with the errors(if you got any).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions out there for Cypress. As a quick solution, you can set a cookie value and decide to skip the particular test. add this code to your `cypress/support/index.js`

```
afterEach(function onAfterEach() {
  if (this.currentTest.state === ‘failed’) {
    cy.setCookie(‘shouldSkip’, ‘true’);
    //set cookie to skip tests for further specs
    Cypress.runner.stop();
    //this will skip tests only for current spec
  }
});
```

You can read more and see the full blog post here:
[Skipping Cypress tests on first failure](https://rajneesh-m49.medium.com/skipping-cypress-tests-on-first-failure-and-saving-resources-2c63e3bb0705)